# Macaw SVG Image

Tags: swift, swiftui, svgkit, macaw

So I am trying to get an SVG image to show in SwiftUI however the documentation to the plugin Macaw is not written well - according to the GitHub.

So how can I the following code to work?

First I import this after pod install:

```
import Macaw
```

then I add this:

```
SVGImage(svgName: "location")
                                       .frame(width: 550, height: 550)
```

However I get:

```
Cannot find 'SVGImage' in scope
```

I have also installed `SVGKit`, I am trying to get it to work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you took the [first part of this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996928/13982463)

But forgot to implement **SVGImage** struct

```
import SwiftUI
import Macaw

struct SVGImage: UIViewRepresentable {

    var svgName: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SVGView {
        let svgView = SVGView()
        svgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0)   // otherwise the background is black
        svgView.fileName = self.svgName
        svgView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return svgView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SVGView, context: Context) {

    }

}
```